# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'aspect_ratio' (T_STRING)

Tags: php, wordpress

I get an error with my PHP script, "Unexpected 'aspect_ratio' T_STRING". Could someone take a look at why this happens?

```
$text_to_be_wrapped_in_shortcode = '<div class="player player-small <?php print apply_filters( 'aspect_ratio' , 'embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9');?>">';

echo do_shortcode( '[sociallocker id="2378"]' . $text_to_be_wrapped_in_shortcode . '[/sociallocker]' );
```

Please help me i'm very thankful to all of yours.

Comment: It's happening because straight after the string `'<div class="player player-small <?php print apply_filters( '` you have placed the word `aspect_ratio`. PHP doesn't understand what this means. And neither do I. But you should start by fixing your quotation marks.

Comment: You need to read up about basic PHP string syntax: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php particuarly how to embed quotes inside a string using the same type of quotes as the delimeter.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to escape your PHP statement.

```
$text_to_be_wrapped_in_shortcode = '<div class="player player-small' . apply_filters( "aspect_ratio" , "embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9") . '">';
```

And then

```
echo do_shortcode( '[sociallocker id="2378"]' . $text_to_be_wrapped_in_shortcode . '[/sociallocker]' );
```

Comment: Error gone, but WordPress theme showing whole page locked from Social Locker Plugin. I think its not right way... :(